# TypeError in a Python script

Tags: python

While running the below python script, getting errors. can someone help?

```
query1 = "SELECT Date AS \"time\",jobType,sum(CJob) AS \"sum(CJob)\" FROM logs WHERE Date = '06/01/2021' and jobType is not null GROUP BY jobType ORDER BY Date"

mycursor.execute(query1)
myresult1 = mycursor.fetchone()
print("Total Completed orders in Logs Table(New DB)                             :%s  " % myresult1)
```

Getting this below error.

```
File "C:\Users\santhosh.mohana\python_scripts\clow.py", line 35, in <module>
    print("Total Completed orders in Logs Table(New DB)                             : %s " % myresult1)
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

When i keep it as %d, i am getting this one

```
File "C:\Users\santhosh.mohana\python_scripts\clow.py", line 35, in <module>
    print("Total Completed orders in Logs Table(New DB)                             : %d " % myresult1)
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

Comment: `myresult1` will be tuple with 3 elements. you have only one placeholder `%s`. And in any case use new-style string formatting or f-strings.

Comment: Great!
It works now
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The content of `myresult` is not a string but more-likely an `int` type. The `%s` formatter would like a string. There are two ways to neatly fix this.

The quickest is a fast conversion before you use the var:

```
#... 
print("Total Completed orders in Logs Table(New DB) :%s  " % str(myresult1))
```

Or alternatively, I love the new string `f` string formatting of which allows injection of variables (*locals*) straight into the string:

```
#... 
print(f"Total Completed orders in Logs Table(New DB) :{myresult1}")
```

No convert required as it uses the standard `__str__` or `__repr__` in the variable.

Some nice info here: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/